# How to effeciently remove character if available at the beginning and end of a string in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, replace

The idea is to remove full stop, commas, quotation if it is available at the beginning and last string in Pandas.

Given a `df` as below

```
data = {'Name': ['"Tom hola.', '"nick"', 'krish here .','oh my *']}
```

The expected output is

```
Tom hola
nick
krish here
oh my
```

I tried the following code, but it did not work as intended

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str[-1:].replace({"\. ": "Na"},regex=True)
```

May I know how this objective can be achieved?

Also, can the approach extended for it to be applied across different columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) if you want replace only colum else use [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).

```
# Using `pd.Series.str.replace`
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r'\.$','')
df          Name
0     Tom hola
1   secondx //
2         nick
3  krish here

# Using `df.replace`
df.replace(r'\.$', '', regex=True)
          Name
0     Tom hola
1   secondx //
2         nick
3  krish here
```

- About regex pattern used in the answer [click here`regex101`](https://regex101.com/r/7QRWNZ/1)

**EDIT:**

You can use `pd.Series.str.strip` to strip `"`, `.` and `*`

```
df['Name'].str.strip(r'\"\.\*')

0       Tom hola
1           nick
2    krish here
3         oh my
Name: Name, dtype: object

# OR
df.Name.str.replace(r'^\W+|(.*?)\W+$',r'\1') # Replaces only values in `Name`
# df.replace(r'^\W+|(.*?)\W+$',r'\1',regex=True) Replaces for whole df
```

- More about regex pattern used in second case [here](https://regex101.com/r/UlHH1U/1)

Comment: Thanks @Ch3steR. I would like to extend this approach so that it can remove the symbol `"` as well. But replacing `r'\.$' ` into `r'\"$'` do nothing.. Also, if `$` indicate end of a string, is there any special symbol to indicate the first string?

Comment: Yes, use `^` for start of the string. @balandongiv

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @Ch3steR. But,still unable to replace the opening quote which exist at the end of the string while using `df.replace(r'\"$', '', regex=True)`. This also apply for removing the same special char at the front using df.replace(r'\"^', '', regex=True)

Comment: @balandongiv Can you post an example to the question exactly what you want to do? Make an example such that it covers all test cases like ending with `.`, starting with `"`.

Comment: I have edited slightly the expected output above. Thanks for your time

Comment: @balandongiv Edited the answer. See if it helps. ;) Feel free to ask if you have any queries.

Comment: @balandongiv Added one more alternative. Not a Regex expert there might exist a much regex than what I posted but this should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

use `(\W)*$` if you want to match all specials characters at the end of the string

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Tom hola.', 'secondx //', 'nick', 'krish here .']})
df['Name'] = df['Name'].replace({r'(\W)*$': ""}, regex=True)
```

Output :

```
         Name
0     Tom hola
1    secondx 
2        nick
3  krish here
```

You can use https://regex101.com to test and better understand what your regex is doing

Comment: Thanks for the response, just to make this approach go further, I replace the `{r'(\W)*$': ""}` into `{r'(\W)*^': ""}` to remove special char at the beginning,but, it does not work as intended.

Comment: To remove at the beginning you can use `r'^(\W)*'`. And if you want to do both at the same time: `^(\W)*|(\W)*$`